# Broken std::unique_ptr in GCC 4.7.2

Tags: c++, c++11, unique-ptr

I'm attempting to use `std::unique_ptr` in order to store the integer handle to some opaque objects. For this purpose, I have defined a custom deleter type which does `typedef int pointer` in order to override the raw pointer type to `int` instead of `int*`. This process is described in the last section of this site: http://asawicki.info/news_1494_unique_ptr_in_visual_c_2010.html

Here is some sample code to better illustrate what I'm attempting to do:

```
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

static void close(int p)
{
    std::cout << p << " has been deleted!" << std::endl;
}

struct handle_deleter
{
    typedef int pointer;
    void operator()(pointer p) { close(p); }
};

typedef std::unique_ptr< int, handle_deleter> unique_handle;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    unique_handle handle(1);

    return 0;
}
```

When I compile this code using GCC 4.7.2, I get the following error:

```
In file included from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.7.2/../../../../include/c++/4.7.2/memory:86:0,
                 from unique_ptr_test.cpp:1:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.7.2/../../../../include/c++/4.7.2/bits/unique_ptr.h: In instantiation of ‘std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>::~unique_ptr() [with _Tp = int; _Dp = handle_deleter]’:
unique_ptr_test.cpp:19:23:   required from here
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.7.2/../../../../include/c++/4.7.2/bits/unique_ptr.h:172:2: error: invalid operands of types ‘int’ and ‘std::nullptr_t’ to binary ‘operator!=’
```

The code of the `~unique_ptr` procedure reads as follows:

```
// Destructor.
~unique_ptr() noexcept
{
    auto& __ptr = std::get<0>(_M_t);
    if (__ptr != nullptr)
      get_deleter()(__ptr);
    __ptr = pointer();
}
```

According to me, the check against nullptr does not make sense since the raw pointer type is `int` (and not `int*` due to overriding it in `HandleDeleter`). Strangely enough, this code compiles with no error under GCC 4.6.1. Upon execution, the sample displays "1 has been deleted!" as expected.

I was wondering if there is any detail I'm overlooking or if it really is a bug within GCC's STL implementation of unique_ptr.

Thanks,

PMJ

Comment: Pro tip: First search the error in *your* code / understanding, and don't instantly blame the implementation to be "broken". Now, `Deleter::pointer` must fulfill the *Nullable Pointer* requirement. This includes comparision against `nullptr`, since `std::unique_ptr` is specified to only call the deleter if `get() != nullptr`. IOW, you'll just have to wrap your `int` and use that as the `pointer` type.

Comment: `std::unique_ptr<T>` means a *pointer to T*. There is no way to have `std::unique_ptr<T>::pointer` be `int`. In other words, you're forgetting the implicit asterisk applied to the first template argument.

Comment: @Xeo:  Why isn't that an answer! :-)

Comment: @Xeo: Thanks for the tip, although I can honestly say that I usually do what you mention (blame my own code first). I really meant "broken" in the sense that what used to compile correctly with a prior version of GCC now fails to compile due to some behaviour changes in the unique_ptr implementation. This applies to the code in the link I provided as well as similar code samples for unique_ptr I've seen on numerous websites. I confess to the bad choice of words, however.

Comment: @GManNickG: This is purely a semantic issue. A handle is basically a special kind of opaque pointer. Beside, if one cannot use anything except T* for the raw pointer type, then why is it explicitly allowed to override the `std::unique_ptr<T>::pointer` typedef by using a custom deleter?

Comment: @pmjobin: Oversight on my part, didn't know. :) Xeo is then right in this regard as the fundamental reason, I attempted (and failed) to give another. The "why" you ask is because it's possible to do so usefully, I assume.

Comment: @Howard: It wasn't because I was dead tired when this question popped up yesterday. :) It is now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As I said in my comment, if the deleter type you pass has a nested `pointer` typedef, it must fulfill the *NullablePointer*  requirements:

`20.7.1.2 [unique.ptr.single] p3`

> If the type `remove_reference<D>::type::pointer` exists, then `unique_ptr<T, D>::pointer` shall be a synonym for `remove_reference<D>::type::pointer`. Otherwise `unique_ptr<T, D>::pointer` shall be a synonym for `T*`. **The type `unique_ptr<T, D>::pointer` shall satisfy the requirements of `NullablePointer` (17.6.3.3)**.

And `§17.6.3.3` then lists all the requirements a type has to fulfill to be a NullablePointer. Certain semantics are listed in a table, where:

> `u` denotes an identifier, `t` denotes a non-const lvalue of type `P`, `a` and `b` denote values of type (possibly `const`) `P`, and `np` denotes a value of type (possibly `const`) `std::nullptr_t`.

```
Expression    Return type                         Operational semantics
P u(np);                                          post: u == nullptr
P u = np;
P(np)                                             post: P(np) == nullptr
t = np        P&                                  post: t == nullptr
a != b        contextually convertible to bool    !(a == b)
a == np       contextually convertible to bool    a == P()
np == a
a != np       contextually convertible to bool    !(a == np)
np != a
```

Now, the simplest solution is to wrap your `int` in a type that provides these semantics:

```
#include <cstddef> // std::nullptr_t

struct handle{
  handle() : value(0){}
  handle(std::nullptr_t) : value(0){}
  /*explicit*/ handle(int v) : value(v){} // make it explicit if you need it
  // special members can be generated

  handle& operator=(std::nullptr_t){ value = 0; return *this; }

  // contextual conversion to bool
  explicit operator bool() const{ return value != 0; }

  int value;
};

bool operator==(handle lhs, handle rhs){ return lhs.value == rhs.value; }
bool operator!=(handle lhs, handle rhs){ return lhs.value != rhs.value; }
// comparision against 'nullptr' is handled by the above operators
// since 'nullptr' can be implicitly converted to 'handle'
```

Comment: Note that you may want to specifically handle comparision against `nullptr` after all, if `0` is a meaningful value for your handle. Or if you have any non-meaningful value, set `value` to that in the `nullptr` constructor.

Comment: Thank you for the in depth explanations. Now, I can clearly see why this approach is wrong. I thought I could save some work by using (coercing) `std::unique_ptr` to store the integer handles. Perhaps it would've been easier to implement unique_handle from scratch after all. :)